# Take element-wise maximum of two columns with an array formula

Tags: google-sheets

I want to take element-wise maximum of two columns, that is pick whichever is larger in every row. So, with the input

```
+-------+
| A  B  |
+-------+
| 3  8  |
| 5  2  |
| 2  7  |
+-------+
```

the output should be a column with 8, 5, 7.

The function MAX can do this for two values like `max(A2, B2)` but when I try array formula

```
=arrayformula(max(A2:A4, B2:B4))
```

the output is just 8, the overall maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's just two columns,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A4>B2:B4,A2:A4,B2:B4))
```